# Why am I getting a banned dependency error in one of the submodule in Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, optaplanner, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have a maven with several modules setup like this:

```
- backend
- frontend
- benchmark
pom.xml
```

When I build the project, I get this error when building the `benchmark` module:

```
[WARNING] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.BannedDependencies failed with message:
Found Banned Dependency: commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2
Use 'mvn dependency:tree' to locate the source of the banned dependencies.
```

I've run `mvn dependency:tree` and from what I can tell, its because the `sendgrid-java` package being used in the `backend` module contains the `commons-logging` dependency. It's a managed dependency so its declared in the root `pom.xml` file and then used in `backend` module.

I'm unable to understand why its giving me this banned dependency error. I've looked at all my `pom.xml` files, and there's no mention of any banned dependencies.

I can solve this problem by putting `<enforcer.skip>true</enforcer.skip>` in the `pom.xml` for the `benchmark` module, but I want to know why this problem is being caused? Where is maven getting the banned dependency from?

Here's my root `pom.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.optaplanner</groupId>
    <artifactId>optaplanner-build-parent</artifactId>
    <version>8.24.1.Final</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.optaweb.employeerostering</groupId>
  <artifactId>optaweb-employee-rostering</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>OptaWeb Employee Rostering as a Service Parent</name>
  <description>
    OptaWeb Employee Rostering as a Service with OptaPlanner on OpenShift 4.
    This project is no longer maintained.
  </description>
  <url>https://www.optaplanner.org</url>
  <inceptionYear>2017</inceptionYear>

  <repositories>
    <!-- Bootstrap repository to locate the parent pom when the parent pom has not been build locally. -->
    <repository>
      <id>jboss-public-repository-group</id>
      <name>JBoss Public Repository Group</name>
      <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
      </releases>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <properties>
    <!-- Define JaCoCo agent argLine property to avoid Surefire failure when JaCoCo is not enabled. -->
    <jacoco.agent.argLine/>

    <sonar.projectKey>optaweb-employee-rostering</sonar.projectKey>
    <sonar.moduleKey>${project.artifactId}</sonar.moduleKey>

    <version.frontend-maven-plugin>1.12.1</version.frontend-maven-plugin>
    <version.node>v16.2.0</version.node>
    <version.npm>7.15.1</version.npm>
    <version.org.apache.poi>4.1.2</version.org.apache.poi>
  </properties>

  <modules>
    <module>optaweb-employee-rostering-frontend</module>
    <module>optaweb-employee-rostering-backend</module>
    <module>optaweb-employee-rostering-benchmark</module>
    <module>optaweb-employee-rostering-docs</module>
    <module>optaweb-employee-rostering-distribution</module>
    <module>optaweb-employee-rostering-standalone</module>
  </modules>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Internal modules -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaweb.employeerostering</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaweb-employee-rostering-frontend</artifactId>
        <type>zip</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaweb.employeerostering</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaweb-employee-rostering-frontend</artifactId>
        <type>pom</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaweb.employeerostering</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaweb-employee-rostering-backend</artifactId>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaweb.employeerostering</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaweb-employee-rostering-backend</artifactId>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
        <type>jar</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaweb.employeerostering</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaweb-employee-rostering-docs</artifactId>
        <type>zip</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.optaweb.employeerostering</groupId>
        <artifactId>optaweb-employee-rostering-standalone</artifactId>
        <classifier>quarkus-app</classifier>
        <type>zip</type>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <!-- BOMs -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
        <version>${version.io.quarkus}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>

      <!-- Excel -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.apache.poi}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>${version.org.apache.poi}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
        <classifier>runtime</classifier>
        <version>${version.jacoco.plugin}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
        <artifactId>auth0</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sendgrid</groupId>
        <artifactId>sendgrid-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.3</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>analyze-only</id>
              <phase>none</phase>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
          <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>${version.frontend-maven-plugin}</version>
          <configuration>
            <nodeVersion>${version.node}</nodeVersion>
            <npmVersion>${version.npm}</npmVersion>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>

  <profiles>
    <!-- TODO: Remove me when Quarkus upgraded to 1.13 -->
    <!-- See https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/14384 for details -->
    <profile>
      <!--
        TODO: For moving the coverage measurement from Travis to Jenkins, add the repository name to
        SONARCLOUD_ENABLED_REPOSITORIES in
        https://github.com/kiegroup/kie-jenkins-scripts/blob/main/job-dsls/jobs/pr_jobs.groovy
      -->
      <id>run-code-coverage</id>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
          <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
          <classifier>runtime</classifier>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
              <configuration>
                <argLine/>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                  <jacoco-agent.destfile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</jacoco-agent.destfile>
                  <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                  <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>jacoco-prepare-agent</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>instrument</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>instrument</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>restore</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>restore-instrumented-classes</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <goals>
                  <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <dataFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</dataFile>
                  <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
              <execution>
                <id>merge-results</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>merge</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <fileSets>
                    <fileSet>
                      <directory>${project.build.directory}</directory>
                      <includes>
                        <include>*.exec</include>
                      </includes>
                    </fileSet>
                    <fileSet>
                      <directory>${project.root.dir}/target</directory>
                      <includes>
                        <include>*.exec</include>
                      </includes>
                    </fileSet>
                  </fileSets>
                  <destFile>${jacoco.exec.file}</destFile>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

I've tried searching in all the `pom.xml` files but there's no settings for the enforcer plugin. My guess is that there is some default configuration causing all this, but I'm not sure what it is.

Comment: *but I want to know why this problem is being caused?* I would guess this is mitigation for [CVE-2021-44228](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell).

Comment: Maven Central will always show you the vulnerabilities reported for a given version: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Maven Enforcer Plugin` provides goals to control certain environmental constraints such as Maven version, JDK version and OS family along with many more built-in rules and user created rules.

Any company, community can create custom rules by their own standards, observations and so on.

In that certain case `OptaPlanner` supports only `SLF4J + Logback`, more precisely they forbid all other logging frameworks (eg. commons-logging, log4j).

So exclude that `commons-logging` dependency if it is possible and use `org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j`.

Otherwise only in backend module disable the `Enforcer Plugin`.

Finally you can override only that certain execution of enforcer plugin

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>ban-forbidden-dependencies</id>
                    <phase/>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

Please note that the Optaweb Employee Rostering project has been archived since Jul 21, 2022. Thus, its dependencies might not match the restrictions defined by the `optaplanner-build-parent` `pom.xml`.

If you seek an example of an employee rostering use case, please have a look at the following quickstart:
https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner-quickstarts/tree/stable/use-cases/employee-scheduling